# Do not show standard Site pages in a Salesforce lightning community

Tags: lightning-community, bestpractice, community-cloud

We have set up a lightning community. When I access it at https://mycommunity.cs1.force.com/s/login, I see an Experience (Community) Builder lightning login page. But when I try something like this (as unauthenticated user) https://mycommunity.cs1.force.com/something, I get the standard Page Not Found (404) Visualforce page.
[image]

A logged in user would see internal org:

[image]

Obviously this is not user friendly and external users would not be happy to see it. So what is a best practice around this situation? How is it usually set up?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by choosing "Use Custom Visualforce Error Pages"
In Settings -> Communities -> All Communities -> Workspaces -> Administration -> Preferences

[image: Use Custom Visualforce Error Pages]

Then go to "Settings-> Develop -> Sites" and scroll to the bottom where you can choose the pages you want to show up.

[image: Use Custom Visualforce Error Pages]

Comment: Thank you for reply. Does it mean that I need to create my own VF pages for that? Is it possible to redirect to lightning pages somehow?